# What if a home game player is physically unable to deal? Skip or substitute?

Tags: texas-hold-em, rules, dealing

A friend has hand tremors that make him unable to deal the cards.  Otherwise he's fully able to play.  How best to include him in a home game?

It seems the two options are to skip his deal or have someone else deal for him.  The latter maintains the seating position advantages/disadvantages.  Is it best then to circulate this responsibility somehow, or to always have the person to his right deal (as if he is my friend, of course, so that the substitute dealer deals first to the SB, the person to the left of my friend)?

I've searched the web extensively and cannot find any reference to any standard or clearly preferred way of managing this.  My friend is new to this group so it would help if I could show them a reference to a standard procedure, that we could agree to beforehand.  Thanks!

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Yes someone should deal for your friend, when he has the dealer button.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think you will find any "official" rules about this situation because in most "official" poker tournaments/cash games the players do not deal themselves anyway.

It would be a bad idea to skip his deal because, as you already pointed out, this would disturb the seating positions. Just have someone deal for him - in the right order of course (clockwise, starting with the small bet). Since this is a home game, you can make the rules - just make sure everyone knows and agrees to them.

Answer (score 1):

Create a token that you can use as a "dealer button."  Something that indicates the dealer position, and let someone else deal for him (player who just dealt, for example).

Poker is a game for everyone. Make it so he can play.